# Pause and Start future scheduled Spring JOB

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've implemented few Spring Batch schedulers using @scheduled annotation which are running at their scheduled time. Now I have a requirement that user can PAUSE and START future scheduled JOB for next run.

I've tried looking in Spring Batch framework. I am getting how to stop/start current running job but I want to stop/start future JOB.

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Please help.

Comment: Spring Batch does not provide scheduling features. What you are referring to is Spring Framework's scheduling capabilities.